# SSH login timeout before authentication

Tags: ssh, rocky-linux

I have an OCI instance running Rocky Linux 9.2. It is running a production website but for some reason I have suddenly stopped being able to log in with SSH.

I have tested the connection to port 22 by using another OCI instance on the same subnet and security list.

I can confirm by checking /etc/secure.log via the web console that connections are reaching the server on port 22. There are messages of rejected root logins and I see an error of: "fatal: Timeout before authentication" that appears when I try to log in with an SSH client.

I know my password is correct (tested and working recently) and I have tested with valid ssh keys too (again recently working). I have tested from different locations around the globe just to be sure and all fail with the same message.

The SSH client gives me a message of: Operation timed out.

So I have ruled out firewall, security lists, sshd server running, and client error.

I have searched and searched the internet for the last couple of days but I could not find anyone with exactly these same symptoms. One of the closest things I found was a reference to changing the system limits that caused the loss of SSH for someone: [Increase FD limitation then SSH not working?](https://serverfault.com/questions/497542/increase-fd-limitation-then-ssh-not-working)

I had been editing my /etc/sysctl.config but the problem persists even after undoing the few changes I made (and rebooting).

I am stumped and would appreciate any pointers to what I might try next.

Thank you!

Comment: Use `ssh -v` on the client side to check negotiation and `tcpdump` to check for packet loss.

Comment: Check MTU settings. Such a behavior often happen if starting packets goes through but first 1500-byte one does not. Change MTU on your client computer to 1280 (very safe for any network) and try again.

Comment: Thanks @AlexD! `ssh -vvv` does not reveal anything different from a working SSH connection other than not displaying any messages after `debug1: Connecting to example.com port 22.` until we see `ssh: connect to host example.com port 22: Operation timed out`

Comment: Thanks @kab00m! I tried a smaller packet size as suggested but the connection still fails.

Comment: `tcpdump ` show no dropped packets during a connection attempt...

Comment: tcpdump will not show big packets if they were dropped somewhere on network. Maybe somehow you can set MTU 1280 on remote server and check again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out Cloudflare does not proxy port 22 which means that traffic gets dropped if going through Cloudflare. The solution turned out to be:

1. Use the IP address directly.
2. Create a subdomain in Cloudflare that is not proxied and connect through that.